# RVM, Rails LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am having a issue getting a new rails project up and running.  Its been a while since I've created a new project, but have been working on various work related projects with many different rails/ruby versions (all fine).  That said, I just tried to create a new project and when I run `rails -v` or `rails new xxxx` for that matter I get:

```
/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/trevor/Desktop/config/boot (LoadError)
from /Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

**Specifics**

**ruby -v =>** `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]` * using RVM
**which ruby =>** `/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby`
**gem list =>** shows all necessary gems (i.e rails, bundler etc)
**rvm info =>**

```
ruby-2.2.2:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin Trevor.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)"
    zsh:         "/usr/local/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "2 months 7 days 5 hours 33 minutes 19 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/trevor/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.2.2p95"
    date:         "2015-04-13"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin14"
    patchlevel:   "2015-04-13 revision 50295"
    full_version: "ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2"
    ruby:         "/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/trevor/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:bin:/Users/trevor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2:/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

**What I've Tried**

- `rvm gemset empty`, empty the current `default` gemset
- `gem install rails`
- Typically I have different gemsets for every project, I switched to one using `2.2.2` with a different gemset, `rails new` does not work in that config either.
- This line in the error seems strange to me: `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/trevor/Desktop/config/boot (LoadError)` Why would rails be looking on the desktop/config for a boot file?
- Preformed `rvm implode`, reinstalled rvm, same results.  However, I did notice that by changing directories I am able to create new projects.  For some reason the error has to do with trying to create a project while in `Users/trevor/Desktop`.

Comment: What version of rvm?

Comment: RVM version is: 1.26.11

Comment: and `which rails` returns?

Comment: `/Users/trevor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rails`

Comment: Assuming that you're working in your Desktop directory and that doesn't have rails files that don't belongs there, then I would probably run `rvm implode`  to nuke the rvm installation and re-install it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do some more searching around, but will probably end up going that route.  I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, but wanted to post in case someone else is in the same boat.  After I realized `rails new` would work in other directories, obviously something was going on with creating projects on the desktop.

Bottom line, make sure you have no file/directories in the directory where your running a rails command named `script`.  There are probably other file/directory names that could cause conflict as well.

Comment: Great tip for a beginner